# Python best practice for when an module is not always available

Tags: python, import

I have a Python code that runs on cuda. Now I need to support new deployment devices that cannot run cuda because they don't have Nvidia GPUs. Since I have many `cupy` imports in the code, I am wondering what is the best practice for this situation.

For instance, I might have to import certain classes based on the availability of cuda. This seems nasty. Is there any good programming pattern I can follow?

For instance, I would end up doing something like this:

```
from my_custom_autoinit import is_cupy_available
if is_cupy_available:
    import my_module_that_uses_cupy
```

where `my_custom_autoinit.py` is:

```
try:
    import cupy as cp
    is_cupy_available = True
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    is_cupy_available = False
```

This comes with a nasty drawback: every time I want to use `my_module_that_uses_cupy` I need to check if `cupy` is available.
I don't personally like this and I guess somebody came up with something better than this. Thank you

Comment: How will you handle all your code that wants `cp.SomeModuleMember()` to exist? Should they throw an error saying the `cupy` module isn't installed, or should they fail silently, or should they not be called at all?

Comment: They should not be called at all

Comment: And how would that work? Suppose you have a line saying `x = cp.dot(y, z)`. What would `x` be if `cupy` doesn't exist? It makes more sense to fall back onto `numpy` and use `numpy.dot(y, z)`, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a module called `cupywrapper` to your project, containing your `try..except`

cupywrapper.py

```
try:
    import cupy as cp
    is_cupy_available = True
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import numpy as cp
    is_cupy_available = False
```

I'm assuming you can substitute `cupy` with `numpy` because from the [website](https://cupy.dev/):

> CuPy's interface is highly compatible with NumPy; in most cases it can be used as a drop-in replacement. All you need to do is just replace numpy with cupy in your Python code.

Then, in your code, you'd do:

```
import cupywrapper
cp = cupywrapper.cp

# Now cp is either cupy or numpy
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
z = cp.dot(x, y)

print(z)
print("cupy? ", cupywrapper.is_cupy_available)
```

On my computer, I don't have `cupy` installed and this falls back to `numpy.dot`, giving an output of

```
32
cupy? False
```

Comment: It seems I cannot import cp from the cupywrapper on my Ubuntu machine (python 3.6.9). I can do it on my Mac (python 3.6.12).

Comment: That's weird. Can you `import cupywrapper`? If not it seems like a problem with relative imports